# Is it possible to automatically generate variables in [R]?

Tags: r

Basically, I am trying to write a function that works with **any** n by m matrix, and need to make it so it gives m different matrices as results. Is there any functionality in R for creating variables within a function?

Comment: Yes, there is. However, you should put all these matrices in a list and return the list.

Comment: How? Let's say i have an n by m matrix, and I want to create m variables, labeled var1, var2, ...varm.

Comment: Now, as Roland alludes to, why do you want to do this? There is generally little good reason to work on a bunch of variables named var1/var2 etc in R. Rather, the data would all be collected in a list, or in your case, in the matrix you already have. If you provide some more details to your question, it may get a good answer though.

Comment: Just realized I wrote "an" instead of "any". I need the function to work with any matrix, and be able to generate an appropriate set of results. If that's incredibly complicated, I'll just stick to making the individual ones.

Comment: the short answer is `?assign` (and `?get` for the inverse operation). The long answer is that you should use Roland's answer to work with lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(42)
m <- matrix(rnorm(9),ncol=3)

#            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
# [1,]  1.3709584  0.6328626  1.51152200
# [2,] -0.5646982  0.4042683 -0.09465904
# [3,]  0.3631284 -0.1061245  2.01842371


fun <- function(mat) {
  result <- list()
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(mat))) {
    result[[i]] <- mat[-i,]
  }
  result
}

mList <- fun(m)

mList[[1]]
#            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
# [1,] -0.5646982  0.4042683 -0.09465904
# [2,]  0.3631284 -0.1061245  2.01842371
```

However, keep in mind that this function is just an educational example. I would probably use `lapply` instead, if I needed exactly this result. But you can put anything you like in a list and let the function return that list (the variables don't need to be of the same type or class).

Comment: So this creates a list of matrices? I think I'll use this. Thanks!